# Como funciona a C99 em relação à C90 para declaração de variáveis no meio do código?

Tags: c, compilação, declaração-de-variável

Na C90 e C89 temos que o *loop* `for` deve ter sua variável declarada anteriormente no começo do escopo da função, exemplo:

```
void main (void)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            /* Qualquer coisa */
    }
}
```

Já para a C99 podemos fazer assim:

```
void main (void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
            /* Qualquer coisa */
    }
}
```

Este foi um exemplo com o `for`, mas isto ocorre com qualquer declaração de variável. Li que esta atualização veio para melhorar o desempenho, declarando a variável somente quando for utilizada, sendo assim, o programa inicializa ocupando menos memória.

Como esta declaração funciona ? O próprio programa faz uma espécie de `malloc` durante a execução ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é bem assim, tem vários pressupostos errados na pergunta.

## O que não mudou

Esta é uma questão que não mudou em nada a execução do programa. Esta mudança é puramente uma nova forma do compilador trabalhar, mas ele não gera código diferente por causa disto.

Não há melhora na performance e não há consumo menor de memória. Tão pouco há piora ou aumento de memória. Não há `malloc()` implícito colocado pelo compilador. Nem haveria motivo para haver.

Declaração de variável e o uso de `malloc()` são coisas ortogonais, uma não depende da outra. Só o programador pode invocar o `malloc()`, o compilador nunca faz isto.

Melhorias de performance podem ser obtidas pelo compilador independente dele ser ANSI inicial, C89, C90, C99, C11, C18 ou qualquer outro padrão da linguagem. Padrão da linguagem e versão do compilador são coisas diferentes. O compilador tem liberdade para fazer o que ele quiser desde que ele siga a especificação da linguagem (uma das listadas acima).

O fato você declarar uma variável antes no início da função ou mais perto do seu uso inicial não muda em nada o programa. Pode mudar se além da declaração também for feita a atribuição, mas aí é a atribuição que muda, em alguns casos.

## O que muda

Declaração é apenas uma reserva de espaço para a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Note que eu disse para a variável e não para o objeto dela.

#### *Stack* X *heap*

Muitas variáveis tem seu objeto se confundindo com o próprio local de armazenamento dela. Caso de todos os tipos primários como `int`, `char`, `float`, até mesmo sequência de dados como estruturas e *arrays* alocados na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Tipos que usam ponteiros armazenam o ponteiro no local da variável e provavelmente alocará o objeto principal em outra área, possivelmente no *heap* através do [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (explicitamente).

Este espaço reservado no *stack* é feito logo no início da execução da função. Em todo compilador C é assim, não importa que versão da especificação ele esteja compatível, até porque a especificação não fala nada sobre isto, mas é algo que na prática é assim.

Note que em C99 a reserva continua sendo feita no início da execução da função (isso é detalhe de implementação, mas todos compiladores agem assim). Com C99 só mudou um pouco a sintaxe permitindo que as declarações podem ser feitas fora do início do bloco de escopo, mas é só mudança sintática. Estas reservas são feitas em [*stack frames*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Note que esta reserva não é uma alocação. O *stack* já está todo alocado na memória. Otimizações do compilador **podem** mudar um pouco este fluxo se ele decidir que é vantajoso.

[image: Stack Frame]

A atribuição é feita no momento em que aparece no código. Se agora a atribuição está no meio da função, é claro que a atribuição ocorrerá naquele momento. Então se a atribuição depender de algo feito antes não haverá problema. Por isto hoje é muito comum declararmos e atribuirmos um valor para a variável no mesmo momento. Antes dos compiladores serem capazes de fazer isto (e alguns já eram capazes antes mesmo de existir o padrão já que padrões costumam oficializar o que os compiladores já fazem) era comum o programador declarar a variável e só atribuir no momento à frente quando ele tinha tudo como ele precisava para fazer isto, assim economiza um acesso à memória

Então não houve uma mudança fundamental na linguagem. Foi mais uma mudança na forma de compilar, trazendo apenas a vantagem de melhor organização do código já que é sempre melhor declarar a variável mais próximo do seu uso, e se possível, em um escopo menor.

E com esta mudança foi possível aproveitar melhor a memória, embora isto tenha pouca relevância.

No seu exemplo a reserva da memória é feita no C89 logo no começo do início da execução da função. No exemplo do C99 ela é feita só no início do bloco do `for`. Isto traz a vantagem de que ela será "liberada" no próprio fim do `for` ao invés do fim da função. Este espaço no *stack* pode ser reaproveitado pela função logo após o fim do `for` e o nome da variável também pode ser reusado embora isto raramente seja algo interessante de fazer. A vantagem do reuso do espaço do *stack* raramente é algo relevante.

## Conclusão

Este é um recurso introduzido para facilitar a vida do programador. Isto é que é importante. Com a forma C99 o programador gerencia melhor o código, entende melhor o que ele está fazendo, mantém em uma região menor o que ele realmente precisa usar. Internamente, na essência, nada mudou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Anteriormente ao C89 esperava-se que o programador já definisse no inicio da função todas as variáveis que ele iria utilizar. Nesse caso eram imediatamente alocadas na abertura da função. Repare que aqui utilizei a palavra "alocadas", mas ela não faz muito jus ao que realmente acontece. Uma breve explicação de como funciona a *STACK*:

Ao inicio do programa um grande bloco de memória é alocado para ser a STACK, você pode considerar que isso é feito via `malloc`. No começo desse bloco é criado um ponteiro chamado `fim_da_stack` e ele indica que tudo depois dele está vazio. Quando uma função qualquer é chamada, ela sabe que a memória logo depois de `fim_da_stack` está disponível, então se quer alocar 20 bytes, basta primeiro fazer `fim_da_stack += 20` para indicar para as funções futuras que aquela memória não está mais disponível, e então basta usar a memória. No momento do `return` é feito `fim_da_stack -= 20` para "liberar" a memória. O importante aqui é que obter mais memória é **muito** barato, muito rápido.

Observe o que acontece:

```
int sum(int* list, int size) {
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  // aqui estamos usando 8 bytes
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result += list[i];
    // aqui ainda estamos usando 8 bytes
  }
  // aqui continuamos usando 8 bytes
  return result;
}
```

Mas se fizer assim:

```
int sum(int* list, int size) {
  int result = 0;
  // aqui estamos usando 4 bytes
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    result += list[i];
    // aqui estamos usando 8 bytes
  }
  // aqui voltamos usando 4 bytes
  return result;
}
```

A diferença é que a variável do loop é criada ao entrar no loop e destruída ao sair do loop, isso permite que a variável sobreviva apenas enquanto é necessária e nem um pouco mais do que isso. É uma regra geral boa de ser seguida: crie as variáveis tão tarde quanto possível e pare as usar tão cedo quanto possível. Isso facilita visualizar o programa pois você programador tem menos variáveis para manter na cabeça enquanto pensa sobre o código.

E como regra geral não se preocupe tanto com velocidade nesses casos, o compilador é bastante esperto e pode fazer coisas como alocar antecipadamente as variáveis ou utilizar a mesma memória para duas variáveis diferentes que não são usadas ao mesmo tempo. Os dois exemplos acima, por exemplo, são considerados equivalentes para o compilador.